# Compass error (can't find proper directories)

Tags: carto, compass

> Compass::SpriteException in Sessions#new
>
> Showing /home/cartodb/cartodb/app/views/layouts/front_layout.html.erb
>   where line #12 raised:
>
> No files were found in the load path matching "icons/*.png". Your
>   current load paths are: /home/cartodb/cartodb/app/assets/images   (in
>   /home/cartodb/cartodb/app/assets/stylesheets/common/header.css.scss)

I've googled and done this: "git submodule foreach git checkout master", and then "rvm use 1.9.2@cartodb --create && bundle install"….
I can get to the next error (and the next) by manually adding various png files but this is not ideal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your question and provide potential answerers with a bit more background on what you are trying to do.  At the moment you seem to be listing an error message, and then some steps you have taken to try and avoid it but not what you were trying to achieve at the outset.

Comment: And what is Compass, in this context?

Comment: Thanks but Xavijam answered this for me.  Somebody upvote this person because I don't have the reputation!  = )

Comment: User25105 you may not be able to upvote yet, but you can still mark @Xavikam's answer correct (which gives a bigger boost than upvoting anyway)

Answer (score 2):

just for anyone to know how,

all you had to do is:

- enter your /cartodb directory
- $ git submodule init
- $ git submodule update

Answer (score 0):

You should update the submodules because that folder doesn't exist anymore:

git submodule update

Also, brach by default in any submodule is 'develop'. You can do it manually going to:

/app/assets/stylesheets/common

And then git checkout develop. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was it.   And apologies for responding so late.

Comment: Great! No worries :)